# How can i force gradle to use to different versions of a dependency?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I have an Android Studio Project with automated testing using google espresso. But espresso uses the android support library 23.0.1 and my application the version 23.1.1.

Now i want to use the newer version of the library for normal builds and the older one only for test cases.

My problem is that gradle forces me to choose one version of the support library. How can i reconfigure gradle to not abort the build process and ignore the clashing dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different versions of the support libraries (why?)

For example you can use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
```

Comment: i already tried this but, gradle does not allow different versions of this library for test and normal build.

Comment: @SimonMüller what does it mean that gradle doens't allow it? and why you should use different version in test and app modules?

Comment: it is default configured to fail if there are version conflicts in android. I need the older version for the testing and the newer one for the produciton build.